# lentitud al insertar registros con sqlserver + genexus

Tags: genexus, sql-server-2008

Buenas tardes comunidad.
Intento insertar registros (respaldar) de una tabla a otra dentro de la misma base de datos.
La base de datos externa está en sql server, tengo la versión genexus 16, tomcat 9.0, y con ambiente web-java.
Al recuperar los registros de la tabla origen mediante un dataview lee y recupera rápido, pero al insertar esos registros en la tabla b mediante un dataview demora 10 minutos y ocupa todo el ancho de banda de tarjeta de red 100 Mbps. He intentado insertando 1 como 1000 pero con el mismo resultado.

He repetido y vuelto ha hacer el programa, cambiando de jdbs driver en el data store, volviendo ha hacer los dataviews pero con el mismo resultado.

Cuál sería el error?

Comment: No entendí bien cómo lo estás haciendo. Entiendo que un For Each a la tabla A y dentro del mismo un NEW en la tabla B. 
De pronto agregando un esquema del fuente o el fuente mismo se puede ver algo, la navegación del mismo puede dar pistas o sino un "log" (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?9135,Log%20JDBC%20Activity%20property)  a ver donde/porqué demora tanto. Insertar un registro, como mencionas, no deberia demorar y usar dataviews tampoco (Salvo que tengas muchos JOINs u operaciones similares pero en el new no deberia influir)

Comment: La tabla b, la utilizas solo para este proceso o la utilizan otros procesos en paralelo? Has intentado con la clausula blocking? SQL bloquea toda la tabla cuando insertas muchos registros.

Comment: Si no es mas que copiar registros de una tabla a otra, yo intentaría directamente con una sentencia SQL Insert into tabla select otratabla , la cual puedes poner en el mismo código Gx.